# Question about Ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm learning Ajax at the moment. The code below basically receives the echo from the PHP and then puts it in element id `games`.

My question is, if I wanted to have Ajax send 3 different HTTP requests to 3 different PHP scripts and if I wanted to retrieve data from each one and then put it in 3 different element id's then would I make 3 copies of this same function? I would imagine that there should be a more efficient way.

```
function showHint(str) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("games").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","hw9.database.php?name="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to do that. You just have to parameterize the function:

```
function showHint(elementid,url,str) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is. Use a JavaScript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) or any other. All of them have built-in Ajax functionality that makes the things you want to accomplish a lot easier.

Example jQuery Ajax request:

```
$('#games').load('hw9.database.php?name=' + str );
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answering my question, not to be rude.

Comment: Actually, he improved upon the solution to your answer.